# sIFR + <span> (other method using image doens't work either)

Tags: sifr

I tried many times and searched this board, but I can't do a simple thing like this:

http://xs.to/xs.php?h=xs139&d=09201&f=menu676.gif

I want to render a menu like this:

item 1 | item 2 | item 3 | .... etc...

"item 1" AND pipe character "|" = sIFR rendered text

---

HTML:

```
<div id="menu"> item 1 <span class="pipe"> | </span> item 2 <span class="pipe"> | </span> </div>
```

---

This part is within my HTML at the very bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var metaroman2 = 

{ src: 'shared/sifr/metaroman2.swf' , ratios:[....7, 1.32....] }; 
sIFR.activate(metaroman2);

sIFR.replace(metaroman2, {

selector: '#menu', css: ['.sIFR-root { background-color: #F9F9F9; color: #1F2956; font-weight:bold;}'], wmode: "transparent" }); 
sIFR.replace(metaroman2, {

selector: '.pipe', css: ['.sIFR-root { background-color: #F9F9F9; color: #1F2956;}'], wmode: "transparent" }); 
</script>
```

---

CSS:

```
.sIFR-active .pipe {

visibility : hidden; line-height : 1em; margin-left : 5px; margin-right : 5 px;
} 
.sIFR-active #menu {

visibility : hidden; line-height : 1em;
}
```

---

The problem is, that the "|" character is beeing put right at the end of the word with no spacing between (5px).

How i want it:
item 1 [5px space] | [5px space] item 2

What i get:
item 1|item 2

**OTHER METHOD:**

If I try it with an image, the image doesnt get displayed at all. ("sIFR.fitExactly = true" has been set in sifr-config)

What I mean with "image": in stead of the pipe sign, an image which represents the pipe sign.

---

html:

```
<div id="menu"> item 1 <img src=...> item 2 <img src=...> </div>
```

---

css:

```
.sIFR-active #menu {

visibility : hidden; line-height : 1em;
}
```

---

script:
This part is within my HTML at the very bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var metaroman2 = 

{ src: 'shared/sifr/metaroman2.swf' , ratios:[....7, 1.32....] }; 
sIFR.activate(metaroman2);

sIFR.replace(metaroman2, {

selector: '#menu', css: ['.sIFR-root { background-color: #F9F9F9; color: #1F2956; font-weight:bold;}'], wmode: "transparent" }); 

</script>
```

I'm sorry for the messy code, but I hope you can make some sense of it.

(edit: have been using sIFR for a few days, simple heading replacing with ratio's work perfectly but the above is beating me up)

Answer (score 0):

wrap every menu item into separate element, and replace that with sIFR selector, don't replace pipes. wrap them into span and style only with CSS.

those replaced items and spans should all be floating block elements.

html:

```
<div id="menu"><a href="#">Item 1</a><span>|<span><a href="#">Item2</a>...
```

css:

```
#menu a , #menu span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: @Skrat

I think that was it! (a quick test gave me a good result).
Thank you very much Skrat!

Comment: sh*t!

I spoke to soon... I forgot to replace the text with sIFR while testing. The moment I tested it whith the replace text script, things went back to the old problem. 

(going test it further now, I still appreciate the above awnser!!!)

Comment: CSS support in Flash isn't advanced enough to directly do what you want to achieve, so Skrat's suggestion is probably the best. Just note that you can't replace `<a>` directly, you have to wrap those in a `<span>` as well…